# URL composer with number randomizer breaks

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to reduce these lines into a single line with a url composer that includes a number randomiser between 1 and 62:

```js
var coverImage = ['/assets/images/covers/cover01.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover02.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover03.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover04.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover05.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover06.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover07.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover08.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover09.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover10.jpg', '/assets/images/covers/cover11.jpg'],
    selectBG = coverImage[Math.floor(Math.random() * coverImage.length)];
$('#hero').css('background-image', 'url(' + selectBG + ')')
```

I've tried with this but I get an error:

```js
$('#hero').css('background-image', 'url('/assets/images/covers/cover' + Math.floor(1,62) + '.jpg ')')
```

Can you help understand what's causing it to break?

Thank you!

Comment: `I've tried with this but I get an error` ... but you dont mention the error in your question. What error do you get?

Comment: I get: SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal ' + Math.floor(1,62) + '. Expected ')' to end an argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only passed in a randomly defined index, but you didn’t include an array variable. You need to write like this:

```
$('#hero').css('background-image', 'url(' + coverImage[selectBG] + ')');
```

This is the second option for a random solution without using an array. The format of numbers up to 10 is in the format `00`, so I had to write some logic that assigns a value to **0** in order to comply with the format of the numbers.

```js
var random_number = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 62);
if (random_number < 10) {
  random_number = '0' + random_number;
} else {}

url = '/assets/images/covers/cover' + random_number + '.jpg';

$('#hero').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');

console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">
```

Comment: Thank you, but can I get rid of the coverImage array? and just have $('#hero').css('background-image', 'url(' ### combine url fragment + random number between 1-63 + .jpg ###')')

Comment: I would like to remove the array since all images are named the same, just changing the number at the end of the filename, so cover01, cover02, cover03.jpg...

Comment: Please note that you are using numbers in the format `00`.

Comment: Ah, right, I just tried changing from 01 to 1 but the error is still the same?

Comment: I made you a solution without an array. Check it out.

Comment: Amazing, that works! It only fails when it tries with 00 which does not exist

Comment: I have already fixed this. Now `00` will not appear in random.